# Qt5 What is a const QModelIndex &sourceParent

Tags: qt, row, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel, qmodelindex

I am attempting to move a row in a QTableView.

I know the current row index and the intended row index. I am attempting to use QAbstractItemModel::moveRow but I am having worst problem with the parameter *const QModelIndex &sourceParent*

Could you explain to me what a *const QModelIndex &sourceParent* is and give me an example on how to set one up?

or tell me a more straightforward way to move a row in a QTableView?

Answer (score 0):

It's for tree-models (when you have parents and childs). If you have a simple model just pass QModelIndex() there and it'd work.